# Mongo-driver Golang - реконнект к монго серверу

Tags: golang, mongodb

Подскажите, как реализовано переподключение приложения (на golang) к MongoDB в случае потери соединения в библиотеке mongo-driver "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"?

На локальном компьютере при отключении монги приложение в течение 30 секунд висит и видимо пытается подключиться - если за это время базу поднять, запрос успешно отрабатывает. 
На продакшн сервере это время гораздо меньше 30 секунд.

Это время - оно задается в настройках клиента библиотеки или в самой монге или от чего еще зависит? Timeout контекста, который существует в клиенте, на эту длительность не влияет.
Монга поднята в контейнере, версия последняя. Код подключения к монге вот такой:

```
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeoutSecond*time.Second)

    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI(connString))
```

Сам запрос вот:

```
err := mr.client.Database(mr.dbName).Collection(mr.collName).FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&p)
```

Comment: timeoutSecond чему равен?

Comment: timeoutSecond  = 600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы можете контролировать работу вашего приложения с помочью `context.WithTimeout` или же с помощью `context.WithCancel(ctx)`. Помимо этого, у вас имеется возможность настроить клиент к базе. 
У клиента есть ряд параметров с таймаутами, одни для выполнения одной операции, другие отвечают за время подключения к серверу(можно сказать время отклика сервера).

когда вы кладете базу и исполняете запрос, то висит канал (go channel), который ожидает выполнения функции, либо завершения контекста, истечения timeout вашего запроса.

```
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return nil, ctx.Err()
    case <-selectionState.timeoutChan:
        return nil, wrapServerSelectionError(ErrServerSelectionTimeout, t)
    case current = <-subscriptionCh:
    }
```

срабатывает `<-selectionState.timeoutChan`, так как по умолчанию его значение 30 секунд

документация нам говорит.

> SetServerSelectionTimeout specifies how long the driver will wait to
> find an available, suitable server to execute an operation. This can
> also be set through the "serverSelectionTimeoutMS" URI option (e.g.
> "serverSelectionTimeoutMS=30000"). The default value is 30 seconds.

а значит, клиент нужно настроить следующим обзом, чтобы продлить время ожидания отклика.

```
client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"),
        options.Client().SetConnectTimeout(time.Second * myTimeout),
        options.Client().SetServerSelectionTimeout(time.Second * myServerTimeout))
```

Comment: Да, решила проблему с помощью установки ServerSelectionTimeout